# Did I do something wrong in this Triage review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

I was [reviewing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8306292) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30618663/how-can-i-add-or-subtract-each-time-when-it-sums-up) and found it OK. To me it was quite clear what the user was asking and there was already a fitting answer.
When looking back at the review I saw that another user marked it as Unsalvageable. I was quite surprised since it is the opposite of my opinion.

Did I do something wrong? Is there something that I missed? I don't review that often, so I surely have a lot to learn.

Comment: It's a really crappy question. First of all, it's not really about programming anything, but about using excel. Second, it doesn't describe the specific problem - "not working" is not a problem description. Third, it is so horribly basic that it probably holds no value to anybody except for the asker - it seems to not work because they misplaced the paretheses, which makes it either a typo or a brain fart. I personally would have reviewed it as "Unsalvageable" with either the "too broad" or the "MVCE" close reason, or possibly the "typo" one.

Comment: Hello meta people. We have someone genuinely interested in improving themselves. If you believe their decisions to have been misguided that's what answers are for. There's no need to be downvoting someone trying to learn - that is the point of this tag after all.

Comment: @l4mpi If you put it that way, it does make a lot more sense. I will surely take a broader look at reviews in the future! I also think your comment is an answer ;)...

Comment: Excel functions are programming; the user just misunderstood the syntax for using them. We have plenty of syntax questions that are on-topic, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17142519 Maybe the OP is coming from somewhere arguably worse, like Stata, where functions must stand alone, so no `total(x)+1` is allowed; and `sum` doesn't even mean sum, but rather cumulative sum. Cut some slack, eh. It definitely was not unsalvageable.

Comment: @pnuts No. However, an Excel elitist with tag-wiki editing privileges doesn't get to define what is on-topic for the site. Complexity is not an accepted criterion. Is it about dropdowns, buttons or shortcuts (as is suited to superuser)? No. Is the question simply a typo, like they meant to type it another way? No. Is the scope of the misunderstanding so broad that an answer cannot reasonably be contained within SO's Q&A format? No. (cont.)

Comment: I'm sure that in the excel world, you guys are hit with clueless questions all the time, but that isn't really a basis for excluding them from SO. The defensive "complex" bit has scarcely been there a week, besides.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I understood the question the first time that I read it, which is an indicator I like to use to determine if something is worth tasking editors to improve. I would have indicated that the question needs improvement which is essentially saying:

*There's enough here to work with, but it needs polishing*

If you take another look at the question, it's what I *envisioned* it looking like if someone spent a minute editing it (which I just went ahead and did).

The question is very unlikely to cause anyone that has ever used excel to strain, but it *seems* on-topic to me (I'm not an excel guru) and (now) reasonably clear, with a couple of good answers.

You didn't do anything wrong, your instinct was it's answerable and had at least one good answer. Just also consider if the current form of the question is okay as a *lasting* artifact, if it could use some cleanup to boot, then it's probably worth editors spending a few cycles cleaning it up.

Comment: Can you confirm that this question is really on topic ? Excel tag speaks of *complex* formulas. I thought this one simple enough to fall in the range of *general computing hardware and software* ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I've seen plenty of equal complexity fare well, but it's a matter of opinion and consensus. My experience with excel isn't sufficient enough for me to really make the call, I don't see it as obviously off-topic, but I could learn something from most simple excel questions. I also dislike closing perfectly answerable questions about a topic because they're 'too easy', I'm jealous when it comes to our content and prefer to keep as much as we can on SO :)

Comment: My problem, is that your anwer has the moderator diamond, so for me (and probably for others) *you are the guy who says the truth* - at least until another mod says something different :-) . I admit the question is not worse than plenty of others, but I was about to vote to close it (it has already 4 votes) and did not because as a mod you say it is on topic.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - Just made an edit, good point.

Answer (score -2):

I think, this question is a little bit unclear. The OP is probably using excel, but he doesn't clarify that. I had voted for "needs improvement" in this case.

I don't think you had done any wrong, it is essentially a vote. Nothing can guarantee that your opinion will always match the collectives, and I think it would be highly harmful if it would be forced. At least, until you don't make some really problematic (f.e. mistakenly approving spam). But nobody on the world made any mistake in his life.

Comment: Do not use *needs improvement* for such a question. It should be used for questions that others can improve. Here *unsalvageable* is best, *looks ok* is acceptable since there's an answer, but *needs improvement* is **wrong**

Comment: @SergeBallesta The "excel" tag shows he uses excel. The intention of the OP is relatively clear, his question isn't. I think editing the question, and asking further clarifications from him in comment could have saved the question.

Comment: That's exactly what HIQ is **not** for. If only OP can fix the question, the HIQ reviewers get in their face a question they just **cannot** improve. *Needs improvement* means *send that in HIQ so that fellows make it good*. It is not appropriate here.

Comment: @SergeBallesta On my opinion, editing excel into the question (and make it more clear in any other sense) had been enough for the question to survive. Yes, the op could have also improve it, but not only he.

Comment: I've read Tim's answer, and its edit to original question. Looks like you are right and I am wrong here. I mainly considered the question off topic because about *general computing hardware and software*. But excel tags explicitely cites *[complex] formulas* as on topic. This one is not particurlarly complex but let's say it is just border line ;-)